# R-Studio crash when calling java code through rJava

Tags: java, r, rstudio, rjava

I am using rJava to call java code and the R-studio keeps crashing after some of my java code has completed. I have not been able to find a single java statement that causes the crash, yet.

A few details:

- I am working on a windows 8 , 64 bit machine
- My java code contains (multithreaded) machine learning optimization code
- The java code uses System.out.println for tracing, which is correctly 
  transferred to the R-Console.
- Removing all traces doesn't help

Has anyone had similar problems?

Comment: And if you run your script outside of RStudio?

Comment: the rJava call is part of an rmd script I need to knitr into pdf, so I really depend on RStudio (actually , thats pretty much the main reason I am using this kind of hybrid coding style here)
However, to isolate the problem I have just executed the code in the native RGui , which crashed as well.